# Firebase DB Key, Name, Value clarification

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase DB as follows:

```
{
  "Kids" : {
    "icon" : "ChildIcon",
    "name" : "Children's",
    "qty" : 2
  },
  "clothes" : {
    "icon" : "MensIcon",
    "name" : "Mens",
    "qty" : 12
  },
  "womans" : {
    "icon" : "WomansIcon",
    "name" : "Womans",
    "qty" : 5
  }
}
```

I want to read the top level list of names.  For example, I am trying to retrieve "Kids, clothes, womans"

I can use this code:

```
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name")   //userId)
    query.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var array = [Categories]()
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let category = Mapper<Categories>().map(JSON: (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as! [String : AnyObject]) {
                array.append(category)
            }
        }
        success(array)
    })
```

to successfully retrieve all of the items with the 'name' field, but how do I retrieve the string for the name of the above level.

that code will return "Children's, Mens, Womans", but I want "Kids, clothes, womans"

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am doing this in Swift, but any help would be accepted!!

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for `child.key`.